# Ctrl-C In VSCode Terminal Does Not Interrupt Docker On Windows

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm working on a Docker container that, under normal circumstances, does not exit, so has no graceful exit logic. I've installed Docker Desktop on my Windows 11 system so I can build and test the container locally without the overhead of pushing to Git and waiting for CI to build.

If I run `docker run --rm -p 80:80 my_container_image` within the VSCode terminal, it runs, as expected. When I press Ctrl-C to send a keyboard interrupt to the process afterward so I can rebuild the image, nothing happens. I have to use the kill terminal function. Why can't I interrupt `docker run` from VSCode?

I'm using Powershell 7.2.6. Docker is configured to use the WSL 2 backend.

What I tried:

- Pressing Ctrl-C in the terminal

What I expected:

- The program to be exited
- Possibly ^C to be printed in terminal

What actually happened:

- Nothing.

Comment: Strange, using CTRL+C in terminal works for me. If you go to `File` > `Preferences` -> `Keyboard shortcuts` and search for `CTRL+C` do you see any non default sources? What is the when clause for your `Terminal: Copy selection` command? Also, are you sure you don't have anything selected in the terminal when pressing CTRL+C?

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts for `Terminal: Copy selection`, and their when clauses, are at defaults. Heck, I didn't even know there were when clauses for hotkeys until now. Deleted the Ctrl-C listing just to check, same problem. Only other listing is for the Vim extension, and its properly configured to only behave as the Vim keybind when Vim mode is enabled (which it generally isn't).

Comment: Interestingly, running `wsl yes` as the first command I can think of and pressing ^C works as expected, even before removing the Ctrl-C terminal shortcut in the settings.

Comment: Excuse me, I was using `docker compose up` to spin up my container. Using `docker run` results in the same behaviour as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-it` to make the session interactive: `docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 my_container_image`.

As stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#assign-name-and-allocate-pseudo-tty---name--it):

> The -it instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the
> container’s stdin; creating an interactive bash shell in the
> container.

Comment: This appears to be a difference in default behavior between Windows and Linux, because previously I would always run `docker run` within a Linux environment and ^C worked as expected without the `-it` parameter. In any case, adding `-it` to the arguments in Windows does solve my problem, so thank you.